# Tag Nukificator: Review and remove tags

Tags: app

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

This is a PHP command-line app designed to quickly review questions with a tag, and easily remove the tag if necessary. Made with the [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) tag on SO in mind.

#### License

MIT license.

#### Download

Download or clone from [GitHub](https://github.com/Undo1/tag-nukificator) and run `php nukificator.php` in the command line from the directory.

#### Platform

Anything that can run a decently new version of PHP.

### Contact

I made it. Ping me in the Tavern if you really want to.

### Code

The code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/Undo1/tag-nukificator).

Comment: Just so people don't look stupid for a second, you need to install CURL support for php. Installing the `php5-curl` package in Debian based distros and most nixes and commenting out the curl extension in Windows.